# Effective nuclear charge and electron repulsion

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atomic-structure

To the best of my knowledge, the effective nuclear charge $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ is usually defined such that the potential energy of an electron in an atom, $\langle V \rangle$, can be expressed as

$$\langle V \rangle = 
  -Z_\mathrm{eff}\langle\psi|\frac{1}{|r - r_a|}|\psi\rangle$$

The Hartree-Fock expression for $\langle V \rangle$, meanwhile, is

$$\langle V \rangle =
  - Z\langle\psi | \frac{1}{|r - r_a|} | \psi\rangle 
  + \sum_i \langle\psi |\hat{J_i} |\psi\rangle 
  - \sum_{i \in \sigma} \langle\psi | \hat{K}_i | \psi\rangle$$

Is there any relation between these expressions? It was taught in college Chemistry that $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ accounts for electron shielding, which is simply electron repulsion effects. Is the effective nuclear charge just a semiempirical value fitted to approximate the total potential energy of an electron in an orbital, or is there another meaning behind the number?

Based on what I know, Clementi et al’s values for $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ are not evaluated based on this principle. Could I inquire why this is not the case?

Comment: Hi @ANZGC, would you consider supporting the creation of a Stack Exchange exclusively for chemical/material modeling and quantum chemistry?  It would be appreciated if you could support the proposal here: [Materials Modeling Stack Exchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=Y2YwYTBkY2Q0MjcxYzE3ZWI5Zjk5Mjc5MDA1MzFjZTg3ZmZiOWE5OWViZmE5MjVkZDc2Y2MxMzE2MTZiNmVmYiLf7rhXKiJ6Kj0sU3oZfGEMsyxfmu5aiXdozkAPC8Zq0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z_\mathrm{eff}$ is an empirically derived value, commonly estimated by Slater's Rules. In the Slater system, a shielding parameter $S$ is calculated for a given electron by adding up the shielding constants for all other electrons on the atom with $n$ equal or less than the electron of interest.

If the electron of interest is in an $s$ or $p$ orbital, the shielding constants for the other electrons are given as:

**1.00** for any electron in a shell with $n$ less than or equal to 2 less than the electron of interest. (Example: For a 3p electron, the shielding constant of a 1s electron is 1, because $3-1\geq 2$)

**0.85** for any electron in a shell with $n$ that is 1 less than the electron of interest.

**0.35** for any electron in the same shell as the electron of interest (except 1s, which fits better to a value of **0.30**)

If the electron of interest is in a d or f orbital, the shielding constants for the other electrons are given as:

**1.00** for any electron in a lower shell

**0.35** for any electron in the same shell as the electron of interest

To calculated the parameter $S$ for a given electron from these constants, one simply adds the constants for all other electrons on the atom. Then the effective charge is calculated as $$Z_\mathrm{eff} = Z_\mathrm{actual} - S.$$

Answer (score 2):

> Is the effective nuclear charge just a semiempirical value fitted to approximate the total potential energy of an electron in an orbital, or is there another meaning behind the number?

No, that's pretty much it. The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_nuclear_charge) has a partial periodic table with some $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ values. If you go further down to larger atoms, it becomes obvious that $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ decreases quite a lot towards the outer shells, so you could argue that the concept has its merits in capturing a quite significant effect.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the “effective nuclear charge” is just a semiempirical value used to approximate electron repulsion effects in an atom?

Comment: Yes, I would say that's a fair statement.